# integerating branch.io sdk with android app , getting classcasteException

Tags: android, classcastexception, branch.io

i followed all the instruction as it is on Branch.io

https://start.branch.io/#/  << followed all the steps in this link. (which key i should use .. test_branch_key or live_branch_key ?? what's the difference in both)

**this is my MainActivity.java file**

```
package absdevelopers.com.finalbranchtest;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import io.branch.referral.Branch;
import io.branch.referral.BranchError;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    Branch branch = Branch.getInstance();
    branch.initSession(new Branch.BranchReferralInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitFinished(JSONObject referringParams, BranchError error) {
            if (error == null) {
                // params are the deep linked params associated with the link that the user clicked before showing up
                Log.i("BranchConfigTest", "deep link data: " + referringParams.toString());
            }
        }
    }, this.getIntent().getData(), this);
}

@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    this.setIntent(intent);
}
```

}

**this is my activity_main.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="absdevelopers.com.finalbranchtest.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**this is my AndroidManifest.xml file :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="finalbranchtest" android:host="open"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data android:name="io.branch.sdk.BranchKey" android:value="key_live_icb6ztmzyA8s5fhGYkqpNipjrEiiUc7F" />
</application>
```

**LOGCAT**

```
03-17 14:24:38.407 30232-30232/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
03-17 14:24:38.434 30232-30242/? E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger:      Broken pipe
03-17 14:24:38.434 30232-30242/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
03-17 14:24:38.539 30232-30232/? E/BranchSDK: Branch instance is not created  yet. Make sure you have initialised Branch. [Consider Calling  getInstance(Context ctx) if you still have issue.]
03-17 14:24:38.539 30232-30232/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
03-17 14:24:38.540 30232-30232/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                               Process:  absdevelopers.com.finalbranchtest, PID: 30232
                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity    ComponentInfo{absdevelopers.com.finalbranchtest/absdevelopers.com.finalbranchtes t.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual  method 'boolean  io.branch.referral.Branch.initSession(io.branch.referral.Branch$BranchReferralIn itListener, android.net.Uri, android.app.Activity)' on a null object reference
                                                    at   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
                                                   at   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
                                                Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean io.branch.referral.Branch.initSession(io.branch.referral.Branch$BranchReferralInitListener, android.net.Uri, android.app.Activity)' on a null object reference
                                                   at absdevelopers.com.finalbranchtest.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.java:25)
                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1220)
                                                   at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5949)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694) 
03-17 14:29:38.617 30232-30232/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 30232 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i got the solution for the problem ..

change

```
Branch branch = Branch.getInstance();
```

to

```
Branch branch = Branch.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
```

in the .java file

Answer (score 1):

Here is information on the difference between **Live** and **Test** keys: https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/integration-testing/guide/ios/#the-test-sandbox-environment

To summarize, you can think of these as separate apps in the Branch system that are simply available from the same Dashboard for convenience. There is no data crossover, both offer identical configuration options, and you use different Branch keys to access each one. Links respect the configuration settings of the Branch key under which they are created.

Comment: You're welcome! Feel free to mark the answer as correct so that others can find it in future :)